# Is it possible to require PyQt from setuptools setup.py?

Tags: python, pyqt, setuptools, distutils

I'm building a small app that uses PyQt and tought it'd be nice to declare that dependency in setup.py.

However, according to [this blog](http://blog.stevenmohr.de/tag/pyqt4/) (first hit on google for pyqt setuptools) says it can't be done, and the last paragraph [here](http://www.commandprompt.com/community/pyqt/c8349) doens't try to do it either.

Ideas? Perhaps I should switch to [PySide](http://pyside.org) which is on [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySide/)?

**Update:**

The obvious `install_requires = [ 'pyqt >= 0.7' ]` in `setup.py` gives me:

```
D:\3rd\BuildBotIcon\my-buildboticon\python>setup.py test
running test
install_dir .
Checking .pth file support in .
C:\Python26-32\pythonw.exe -E -c pass
Searching for pyqt>=4.7
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyqt/
Reading http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/
Reading http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download
No local packages or download links found for pyqt>=4.7
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pyqt>=4.7')
```

Comment: look here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt/4.8.2

Comment: @singularity: That page doesn't help, there's nothing downloadable that setup.py can use there, or in the linked-to pages

Comment: Anyone know if this is still true for Python 3 and PyQt 5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the accepted answer was originally correct [Python Wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) now provide a means to install C extension packages such as PyQt5 without the need for compilation from source.

PyPi currently has `.whl` files for PyQt5 on Python3 for multiple platforms, including [MacOS X, Linux (any), Win32 and Win64](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5/5.6). For example, this is the output when pip-installing PyQt5 on Python3 on a Mac:

```
mfitzp@MacBook-Air ~ $ pip3 install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Downloading PyQt5-5.6-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (73.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 73.2MB 2.5kB/s 
Collecting sip (from pyqt5)
  Downloading sip-4.18-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 49kB 1.8MB/s 
Installing collected packages: sip, pyqt5
Successfully installed pyqt5-5.6 sip-4.18
```

If you are targeting Python3+PyQt5 then you should have no problem specifying PyQt5 as a normal dependency in `setup.py`.

Answer (score 5):

Right, the PyQT packages are not using distutils / setup.py for it's installation, so they can't be installed with easy_install or pip. You need to download and install it manually.

That also means you should *not* put it in your `requires` metadata, as easy_install and pip then will try to install it and fail.

I don't know if PySide is any good, but is also has not setup.py, and also refuse to install with easy_install/pip, so not a good option. :)

Another option is to repackage PyQt with distutils, but that may be a lot of work.

Comment: Hi, since this is a while back, I wanted to confirm the same thing again. Is PyQt4 still not available on PyPi?

Comment: @gravetii: Looks like it is available now: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt4/4.10.3

Comment: @dotancohen: No, it's still only a page with metadata, no downloadables.

Comment: its too bad, why a python package not using setuptools ?

Comment: you mean distutils. Setuptools is optional. And you would have to ask the developers.

Answer (score 3):

While you can `pip install pyqt5` thanks to the now available wheels (as suggested by @mfitzp), it cannot be required from `setup.py` via `install_requires`. The reason is that `setuptools` doesn't know how to install wheels which `pip` knows how to, and PyQT5 is only available as wheels on PyPI (there is no source distribution, i.e. no `tar.gz` file). See this [email](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-March/030228.html) and that [bug report](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917) for details.

Answer (score 2):

**[Setuptools >= 38.2.0](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1200) now knows how to install wheels.** The trivial answer, therefore, is to install a recent version of setuptools and require that your enlightened userbase does so as well. To enforce usage of setuptools >= 38.2.0 at installation time, see [this relevant answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049510/2809027).

Since setuptools 38.2.0 was released over a year ago, all prior answers to this question are horrifyingly obsolete, blatantly wrong, and less than useful.