# Check all dependencies of python software before installing in window

Tags: python, installation, windows-installer, pyqt4, setup.py

i make the single exe file for installing my software in window using 
"python setup.py bdist_wininst" but when install this software using exe it check only for python install in system or not , it does not check other dependencies like pyqt ,pycurl library . how i modify this setup file so the generated exe file first check all dependency present in window system before installing if not then install all dependent library.

setup.py file

```
setup(name='XYZ',
      version='1.0',
      description='application',
      author='Arjun Jain',
      author_email='xxxxx',
      url='xxxx',
      download_url='xxxx',
      packages=packages,
      data_files = data_files,
      scripts = ['xyz'],
      classifiers = ['Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
                   'Intended Audience :: Developers',
                   'License :: GNU',
                   'Operating System :: OS Independent',
                   'Programming Language :: Python',
                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
                   'Programming Language :: PyQt :: 4.6',
                   ],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `install_requires` keyword argument to `setuptools.setup()` to specify other packages your package requires.

Note: according to the SO question [Is it possible to require PyQt from setuptools setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628519/is-it-possible-to-require-pyqt-from-setuptools-setup-py) you cannot get setuptools to install it for users who have a Python distribution that's missing it. Anything available from pypi should be installable this way.