# Why is PyQt4 not available on the Python Packaging Index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, setuptools

Well, I wrote a small app that uses PyQt4 and want to distribute it. But the problem is that I have to ask the users to manually install PyQt4 because it cannot be done using `setuptools`.

So, in reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628519/is-it-possible-to-require-pyqt-from-setuptools-setup-py), I wanted to ask if anyone knew the reason why PyQt4 is not on PyPi?

Also, is there any other possible way I could include PyQt4 in my setup.py so that users do not need to install it manually?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because it requires `Qt` which is not a python package and hence can't be installed using `setuptools`?

Comment: It's pretty pointless asking on SO why PyQt is not on PyPI. Ask the maintainer of PyQt about it on the [mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because they do not provide a `setup.py` at the root of their package, and thus it can't be handled by the python packaging system. The `setup.py` is the script that defines all the information for . So it has to be handled by your distribution's package management system.

You could add in your `setup.py` a function that downloads and install pyqt4 and make that function called at install.