# Can I use setup.py to pack an app that requires PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, setup.py

I looked this question here:

[Is it possible to require PyQt from setuptools setup.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628519/is-it-possible-to-require-pyqt-from-setuptools-setup-py)

What's the proper way of distributing a python application that has a gui and it's based on PyQt ? (I am using PyQt5 and Python3)

I am still learning how to distribute things, so I don't know if my question makes sense.

---

Edit:

The answer is correct, `sudo pip3 install .` worked for me for my own **setup.py** file, but apparently pyqt5 doesn't include QtWebKitWidgets module, and it isn't available for installation in a separate package in pip3. So now I am thinking of moving away from Python completely and go with Javascript + Electron as a multiplataform easy to run language for development.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Can I require PyQt5 via setup.py?

In a word *yes*, as long as you restrict your support to PyQt5 and Python3.

The requirements specified in `setup.py` are typically provided by requesting packages from the Python Package Index (PyPi). Until recently these packages were source only, meaning that an installation depending on PyQt5 would only work on a system where it was possible to build it from source. Building on Windows in particular requires quite a lot of set up, and this would therefore put your application out of reach for anyone unable or unwilling to do this.

*Note: As far as I am aware, it was never actually possible to build from source via PyPi. The standard approach was to download the source/binaries from [Riverbank Software](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) and build/install from there.*

This problem was solved by the introduction of [Python Wheels](http://pythonwheels.com/) which provide a means to install C extension packages without the need for compilation on the target system. This is achieved by platform-specific `.whl` files. Wheels for PyQt5 on Python3 are available on PyPi for multiple platforms, including [MacOS X, Linux (any), Win32 and Win64](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt5/5.6) which should cover most uses.

For example, this is the output when pip-installing PyQt5 on Python3 on a Mac:

```
mfitzp@MacBook-Air ~ $ pip3 install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Downloading PyQt5-5.6-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (73.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 73.2MB 2.5kB/s 
Collecting sip (from pyqt5)
  Downloading sip-4.18-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 49kB 1.8MB/s 
Installing collected packages: sip, pyqt5
Successfully installed pyqt5-5.6 sip-4.18
```

To set PyQt5 as a dependency of your own package simply specify it as normal in your `setup.py` e.g. `install_requires=['PyQt5']`

### What's the proper way of distributing a Python GUI application?

Here you have a few options. The above means that anyone with Python3 installed can now install your application using `pip`. However, this assumes that the end-user has Python and knows what `pip` is. If you are looking to distribute your application with a Windows installer, MacOSX 'app' bundle, or Linux package, you will need to use one of the tools dedicated to that purpose.

#### Windows

- [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) is a cross-platform packager that can package Python applications for Windows, Mac and Linux. It works by analysing your project and *freezing* the required packages and subpackages. Success depends largely on which packages you depend on and their complexity/correctness.
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is another cross-platform packager that can package Python applications for Windows, Mac and Linux. This works in a similar way to cx_Freeze and will likely perform both better/worse depending on the packages.
- [PyNSISt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pynsist) builds NSIS installer packages for Windows. This has the advantage of being very straightforward: it simply packages all the files together as-is, without 'freezing'. The downside is that packages can end up very large and slower to install (but see the file-filter options). It now supports bundling of `.whl` files which will solve this in many cases. By far the easiest if you're targeting Windows-only.

#### MacOSX

- [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) see above.
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) see above.
- [Py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app) creates `.app` bundles from the definition in your `setup.py`. Big advantage is the custom handlers that allow you to adjust packaging of troublesome packages. If you're only targetting MacOSX this is probably your best option.

#### Linux

- [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) see above.
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) see above.
- [stdeb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb) build Debian-style packages from your `setup.py` definition.

*Note: It is possible to write a very complex `setup.py` that allows you to build using one or more tools on different platforms, but I have usually ended up storing separate configs (e.g. `setup-py2app.py`) for clarity.*

Comment: So I can write `install_requires=['PyQt5']` inside setup.py now?

Comment: @Elric sure can — just tested it here to be sure, and it's fine.

Comment: Ok, tested here. Wheels still aren't available for Ubuntu (and I think any other Linux distribution). So it won't work unless you are in Mac OS.

Comment: @Elric Not just MacOS X but also Win32 and Win64 are there and work (just tested here). What does it give when trying on Ubuntu? The "manylinux" should work - although that wheel is 64bit only so wont work on 32bit linux.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) too - I switched to it from cx_Freeze because of various problems and it not being maintained very well, and I'm really happy with PyInstaller.

Comment: Linux wheels probably require a new version of pip to install them - if they're not installing, try `pip install --upgrade pip` first.

Comment: Pynsist can now build installers using wheels, which makes it super easy to package a PyQt5 app. Example config file here: https://github.com/takluyver/pynsist/blob/master/examples/pyqt5/installer.cfg

Comment: @TheCompiler thanks for the tip, I completely forgot about PyInstaller (not used it before, but will give it a go).