# add PyQt5 to `install_require`

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Here is a part of my code: (**setup.py**)

```
args = {
    'name' : 'ModernGL.PyQt5',
    'version' : Version,
    'description' : ShortDescription,
    'long_description' : LongDescription,
    'url' : 'https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL.PyQt5',
    'download_url' : 'https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL.PyQt5/releases',
    'author' : 'Szabolcs Dombi',
    'author_email' : 'cprogrammer1994@gmail.com',
    'license' : 'MIT',
    'classifiers' : Classifiers,
    'keywords' : Keywords,
    'packages' : [],
    'ext_modules' : [],
    'platforms' : ['any'],
    'install_requires' : ['ModernGL', 'PyQt5']
}

if target == 'windows':
    args['zip_safe'] = True

setup(**args)
```

If I install manually **PyQt5** the **setup.py** will succeed, otherwise will fail.

Is it possible to add **PyQt5** to the dependency list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributions for `PyQt5` aren't on PyPi.  You would have the same problem with any other python library that doesn't use the python distribution tools.  The `PyQt5` project doesn't have a `setup.py` installer.  `Qt` and `PyQt` are generally installed via OS package managers or installation executables distributed by the software vendors that produce those libraries.

You can include `PyQt5` in the requirements, but your users are still going to need to install `PyQt5` using a separate installer.  `pip` and `setuptools` won't be able to resolve and install it.

Comment: there is no source distribution so no `setup.py`

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs Wow, that's new!  Hadn't seen pyqt on pypi before.  Are you using python 3.5?  It looks like they only have `whl`'s for 3.5

Answer (score 1):

Possible to install with `pip install pyqt5` but impossible to require from `setup.py` because there is no source distribution on PyPI and `setuptools` does not know how to install wheels. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598092/3734066).