# setup.py: require a recent version of setuptools before trying to install

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, install-requires

I'm creating a package that has `'typing;python_version<"3.5"'` in it's `install_requires`. Apparently, this kind of [dependency specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#examples) has only been implemented in recent versions of `setuptools`. If the `setuptools` on the user's machine is old they'll get:

> 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected version spec in
>   typing;python_version<"3.5" at ;python_version<"3.5"

The easy solution is to tell the users to `pip install 'setuptools>=36.2.1'` before `pip install my-package`. (Note that `36.2.1` is just a version that I know works, not necessarily the the absolute minimum requirement)

But is there any way to specify this requirement in `setup.py` so that it gets done automatically? Adding `setuptools>=36.2.1` to `install_requires` and `setup_requires` did not work. It says `Installed /tmp/pip-si2fqg-build/.eggs/setuptools-38.2.5-py3.3.egg` and then gives the same error above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't update `setuptools` and use its code in the setup script in one pass. I see two possible solutions: If you want to support old versions of `setuptools`, you can't use env markers. Implement the check yourself by using `sys.version_info`:

```py
import sys
from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.1',
    packages=[],
    install_requires=['typing'] if sys.version_info < (3, 5) else []
)
```

If you don't want to support old versions of `setuptools`, check its version and abort early, informing the user:

```
import sys
from distutils.version import StrictVersion
from setuptools import setup, __version__


if StrictVersion(__version__) < StrictVersion('20.2'):
    print('your setuptools version does not support PEP 508. Upgrade setuptools and repeat the installation.')
    sys.exit(1)


setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.1',
    packages=[],
    install_requires=['typing;python_version<"3.5"']
)
```

Comment: The problem with the first approach is that if someone creates a wheel file using Python 3.5 or later, then the created wheel will not include the `typing` requirement and therefore that wheel won't install correctly on older python versions.

Comment: Usually, it's the project maintainer/developer who creates the wheels and uploads them to PyPI. He is responsible of building wheels that run on every platform/language implementation that are advertised to be supported (smth like `mypkg-0.1-cp35.cp36-abi3-any.whl` could be imaginable). If someone pulls your source code and builds a wheel that doesn't run, you can't be responsible for that ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I just learned about [PEP 518 -- Specifying Minimum Build System Requirements for Python Projects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/) that addresses this exact problem.

In short, this accepted PEP proposes to store dependencies in TOML format, in a file named `pyproject.toml`. For most Python projects the contents of this file will be:

```
[build-system]
# Minimum requirements for the build system to execute.
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]  # PEP 508 specifications.
```

In the case of this specific question, we just need to replace `"setuptools"` with `"setuptools>=36.2.1"`.

The bad news is that `pip` does not support this yet. The good news is that [it is implemented](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4144/files) and [will probably be shipped with pip 9.1](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4144#issuecomment-263653485).